What were your biggest challenges renting a place in Japan as a tourist?
I’m really curious about the process of finding and renting a place to live in Japan. If you’ve ever gone through this, I’d love to hear your personal stories or any major hurdles you faced. Is there anything you want to be improved?

Welcome to TSE. What is the actual problem you need help with?

For how long? Where?

The title clearly says “as a tourist”, so this is necessarily a (relatively) short-term rental and belongs in travel.SE IMHO. But renting for 2-3 weeks and renting for 3 months may involve very different things.
